# Why does Firefox kick off the Java Runtime Environment for some web sites?

Tags: java, firefox, plugins

I have discovered that navigating to a site that I control will kick off JRE (observed in Task Manager) if I browse with FireFox and if FF has the Java(TM) Platform installed as a plugin. The site does not need Java (it does use JavaScript) and if the Java Plugin is disabled on FF then the JRE is not loaded.

Does anyone know why this happens?

I do have one theory but it's a weak one: The site uses compression when sending HTML to the browser to make it faster and more responsive. I am wondering if the Java Platform has a more efficient decompressor and if Firefox sees that plugin available it uses it to run the page decompression instead of using its built in one.

Comment: Since you control the site, you could test your theory by temporarily turning off compression.

Comment: Does this site has some advertisements? Perhaps some of those are using Java ...

Comment: @Stephen C - turning off compression is really difficult as it's done in code and is not an IIS config.

Comment: @Janne - yes it has AdSense

Comment: So, my wild guess is that those advertisements are Java-based :)

Comment: @Janne - AdSense is Javascript based, not Java-based.

Comment: @Guy are you able to post some of the skeleton (i.e. anonymised) HTML?

Comment: Catchwa: yes, I know. What stops it to print required tags for launching Flash/Java applets? It uses at least Flash ads all the time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering if the Java Platform has a more efficient decompressor and if Firefox sees that plugin available it uses it to run the page decompression instead of using its built in one.

This sounds incredibly dubious. Common sense says "no".

Comment: I write java and I can say that there is no way Java is faster than C/C++.

Comment: What does that have to do with decompressing gzip content?